# Official Zabbix Server MySQL docker image fails start mysql upon container launch

Tags: docker, zabbix

I want to use the official Zabbix images to create a containerized Zabbix service, including the web interface. I landed here: https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql but the instructions are not entirely clear.

I chose zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:ubuntu-4.4-latest and created a container with this syntax:

```
docker run --name somebizzare_zabbix-mysql -e DB_SERVER_HOST="docker.jojo.yo" -e MYSQL_USER="zabbix" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="not-real-one" -d zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:ubuntu-4.4-latest
```

The above produced no errors **but** when I ran  `'docker logs somebizzare_zabbix-mysql'`  I saw:

> **** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...

and when I enter the container I do not see any instance of MySQL mysqld running.

Shouldn't the container start MySQL automatically or is this considered bad practice?
I do not know the correct way to start mysqld from inside a Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.

```
  dpkg -l |grep mysql
```

tells me there is no mysqld installed. zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql
 is 'database support' only.

I suppose I need another container for the actual database.